# Read Value Of Html.TextAreaFor()

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

If I have a

```
Html.TextAreaFor(x=>x.Name)
```

and I want to read its value how do I do it, because this does not have an id??
Also I want to put a validation message below it if the value entered by user in this box is incorrect on pressing of a button. What is the way to populate the error instead of using a mvc architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read the value on the server side, just look at the `Name` property of your Model class.

If you want to be able to read the value using jQuery, add an `id` to the textarea like this:

```
Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Name, new { id = "someId" })
```

And then:

```
var value = $("#someId").val();
window.alert("The value is: " + value);
```

If you want completely customized validation without using `DataAnnotations` or other validation technologies, just add a `<span />` after the textarea, and then write javascript to check the value of the textarea, and hide/show/populate the `<span />` accordingly.

```
var myClickHandler = function(event) {
    var value = $("#someId").val();
    if (/* failing validation expression */) {
        $("#errorSpan").text("Bad bad value!").show(100);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that even the parameter here acts as an id. I can also say

```
var value = $("#Name").val();
```

to get the value of

```
Html.TextAreaFor(x=>x.Name)
```